# java rule based data collection

Tags: java, xml, rules-engine

I'm building a home project using EWS and SQLite.
I have a bunch of really similar (and not so similar) Mails (that hava the usual subject sender body etc fields). 
These mails contain similar information and i would like to collect them into a sqlite db.
Also i want to separete the collection logic from the main code (for mgmt purposes) so I was thinking an xml that would describe different conditions if which are met data collection begins according to that xml object eg.

```
<xml object>
<Conditions>
<and><Sender>exmaple@senderdomanin.com<Sender>
<!--Regular expressions would be nice-->
<Body> ^Hello, <Body></and>
</Conditions>

<Collection>
<Exmaple data1><Sbuject></Exmaple data1>
<Exmaple data2><Attachment Line=2></Exmaple data2>
<Exmaple data3><Mail header attribute=X-mailer></Exmaple data3> 
</Collection>
</xml object>
```

If the conditions are met the sqlite db would be updated with the Subject line, the second line from the atachment and the X-mailer property.

Any help is appreciated! 
Im open to throwing out my xml idea if there is a better existing lib for similar tasks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing your conditions and actions to an XML/JSON and put it aside is a plausible solution, albeit writing it to this format and parse it may be harder to implement and extend/maintain later.

Depending on your requirements and the system that you implement;

It may be more appropriate to create an object class that implements functions "match" (for the conditions) and "execute" (for the actions) and then:

- serialize
- put in an ORM db
- pass them through a shared-memory data structure
- etc.

And let the collector process/thread/system to receive the object and invoke match and (depending on its' result) execute.